# Slack api - why does the App Manifest link not appear?

Tags: slack-api

In my Slack API account, I am trying to locate the App Manifest in order to export my current apps manifest. The Slack API guide (https://api.slack.com/reference/manifests#exporting) states there should be an App Manifest section, but I do not have this. Why not?